# Fitting an image in html

Tags: html, css

how do I fit the image in the blue rectangle?
I have tried resizing the image but the image will be blurred.
[image]

Below is my code:

```
<body>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey; font-size:30px; display:inline-block;">

<!-- Text -->
Our PCBA products are used in the audio, communication, computer peripheral,<br> 
home electronics, and entertainment industries. As existing markets grow and new<br> 
ones emerge, SCOPE is constantly expanding its resources and capabilities to<br> 
meet its customers' new and current needs. SCOPE practices selective investment<br> 
in the best and latest in manufacturing equipment as it continues to strive for<br> 
excellence in the electronics industry to provide a truly cost effective one-stop<br>
manufacturing facility for high quality products and services.
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block; position:absolute; top:99px; left:1000px">
<img src="Company.jpg" style="width:60%;">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Check this link to find out the object-fit property of CSS. This will surely help https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok guys.
Manage to solve it with Hadi Mir advice.
Have to use "object-fit;fill".
Here is the code I used.

```
<img src="Company.jpg" style="width:535px; height:240px; object-fit: fill;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your image like this:

```
<img src="Company.jpg" style="width:100%; object-fit: cover;">
```

Comment: The image disappeared

Comment: Remove the `height` attribute.

Comment: The image is there now, but part of it is over the the bottom border line

Comment: So then just simply define a height with the `height` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `object-fit: cover;`

> The CSS object-fit property is used to specify how an  or  should be resized to fit its container.

```
<div style="display: flex">
    <div style="background-color:lightgrey; font-size:30px; display:inline-block;">
       Our PCBA products are used in the audio, communication, computer peripheral....
    </div>
    <div style="height: 200px">
        <img src="Company.jpg" style="object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 200px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain what object-fit:cover do exactly

Comment: Thanks for correction. I'll try to improve my answer next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
 <div style="background-color:lightgrey; font-size:30px; width:60%;">

<!-- Text -->
 Your text 
<!-- ---- -->
 </div>

 <div style="position:absolute; top:99px; left:1000px; width:40%;">
  <img src="Company.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```